# Can't get some BIM360 folders by forge-apis

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I use forge-apis npm package. 
When I try FoldersAPI.getFolderContents, I can get some folders but can't get others.
All folders are visible from BIM360 folder tree view.
What is different?
How I can get all folders?

Comment: Please provide the request and responses so we can better tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check would be the 2-legged vs 3-legged authentication. The request for [listing the contents of a folder](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET) supports both, and it's possible that using the 2-legged token in your code would exclude certain items and folders from the listing.

If you're still having issues, please send us more details about your scenario (Forge client ID, folder ID, etc.) to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` and we will investigate it on our end.